# Insertar datos desde campos dinámicos

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Estoy tratando de insertar datos desde campos dinámicos generados con *jquery*, en los cuales puedo agregar y eliminar dichos campos, el atributo `name` lo voy incrementando para diferenciarlos (`agr0`, `agr1`, `agr2`, `agr3`....). El problema lo tengo al intentar insertar datos después de haber borrado algún campo, por ejemplo si borro el campo `agr2` mi código inserta solo `agr0` y `agr1` dejando fuera el `agr3`.

Este es el código que estoy utilizando:

```
$i=0;
while(isset($_POST['agr'.$i],$_POST['mon'.$i],$_POST['date'.$i])){
  mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO monitoreo VALUES (null, '".$_POST['agr'.$i]."', '".$_POST['mon'.$i]."', '".restaurarFormatoFecha($_POST['date'.$i])."', $folio)") or die (mysqli_error($con));
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso ocurre porque tu ciclo dice *Mientras exista.....* se ejecutara tu codigo, si no, no sigue le ciclo. Cuando `while` comprueba que dicho elemento no existe corta el ciclo.

Lo mejor que puedes hacer es recorrerlo con un ciclo `for` en este caso

```
[0] = arg0
[1] = arg1
[2] = arg2
[3] = arg3
...
```

Si tu eliminas `arg2`

```
[0] = arg0
[1] = arg1
[2] = arg3
```

Tambien el problema que tienes es que cuando generas los campos dinamicos, si tu generas 4 y eliminas 1, los indices de `arg1`, `arg2`.... deberian cambiar y disminuir en 1.

Comment: muchas gracias sioesi, tus recomendaciones me ayudaron a soluciarlo, lo hice con arrays